# How can I change $record in mutt depending on the from address?

Tags: mutt

I use multiple accounts in mutt, and wish to save sent messages to different `$record` directories. I am aware of `folder-hook`; if I compose in different folders, I can change `$record` depending on the associated account of the initial folder.

However, sometimes, I might want to compose from a different folder, or forward an email to one account from another, or reply from a different account, or change my mind mid-composition (I have `set edit_headers=yes`). Hence, it makes more sense to save the sent email to a specific directory based on the `from` field. Is that possible?

I understand that `fcc-hook` could change `$record` based on *recipients*, but I'd like to change it based on sender instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `fcc-hook` to change the folder depending on all sorts of parameters.

```
fcc-hook '~f foo@example.com' '=foo-folder'
fcc-hook '~f bar@example.com' '=bar-folder'
```

I also use it to depend on the subject (all messages whose subject contains "ISDN" go to my =ISDN folder, for example),  use '~s' for that.

Comment: Thanks @wurtel, I'll check it out in the next day or so.

Comment: Works great! Thank you (+1). One minor quibble: `fcc-hook` appears to only fire after the first edit of the message. If I try to postpone the editing of the message and re-edit, including changing the "from" address, `fcc-hook` will not fire again, and I'm stuck with the initial choice. Is there a way to make it fire after every edit of the message?

Comment: It also doesn't work if I complete the first edit of the email, then change the from address with `<Esc>`, `F`.

Comment: I don't think you can perform the hooks again, unfortunately.

Comment: Okay, I thought as much. I'll leave the question open for a few more days to see if anyone else can add something, otherwise I'll accept your answer. Thanks again.